# How to display image and text beside each other Itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Hi I am trying to create an Invoice where the company logo and the address are displayed next to each other. The company logo is displayed on the left and the text beneath it. I tried to display the text next to the logo to the FAR RIGHT but it didnt come.Please help.

```
public class Test {
    /** Path to the resulting PDF */
    public static final String RESULT = "C:/ex/test.pdf";

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param    args    no arguments needed
     * @throws DocumentException 
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        new ComCrunchifyTutorials().createPdf(RESULT);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a PDF with information about the movies
     * @param    filename the name of the PDF file that will be created.
     * @throws    DocumentException 
     * @throws    IOException
     */
    public void createPdf(String filename)
        throws IOException, DocumentException {

        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));

        document.open();

       Image image = Image.getInstance("C:/Users/user/Desktop/New folder (3)/shoes/shoes/web/images/abc.jpg");
                                                        image.scaleAbsolute(150f, 50f);//image width,height   


Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
Phrase pp = new Phrase(200);
p.add(new Chunk(image, 0, 0));
pp.add(" a text after the image.");

p.add(pp);
document.add(p);

        document.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you try to convert html to pdf? just make html page with your image and invoice and then try to conver html to pdf, it's works

Answer (score 18, accepted):

People usually achieve this by using a `PdfPTable`. See for instance the [ImageNextToText](https://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/ImageNextToText) example:

[image]

This is the code that creates the PDF and the table with two columns:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 2});
    table.addCell(createImageCell(IMG1));
    table.addCell(createTextCell("This picture was taken at Java One.\nIt shows the iText crew at Java One in 2013."));
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

This is the code that creates the cell with the image. Note that the `true` parameter will cause the image to scale. As we've defined that the first column takes half the width of the second column, the width of the image will take one third of the width of the complete table.

```
public static PdfPCell createImageCell(String path) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Image img = Image.getInstance(path);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(img, true);
    return cell;
}
```

This is one way to create the cell with the text. There are many different ways to achieve the same result. Just experiment with *text mode* and *composite mode*.

```
public static PdfPCell createTextCell(String text) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(text);
    p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    cell.addElement(p);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hello Bruno Lowagie Thank you so much for the above post.It is finally working now.

Comment: Now all you have to do, is to accept the answer ;-)

Comment: where to get image path??

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was working in existing functionality and had to do so with in a cell. So here is what I did

```
public PdfPCell buildDesiredCell() throws Exception {

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();

PdfPTable headerTable = new PdfPTable(2);
headerTable.setWidthPercentage(100f);

PdfPCell leftCell = new PdfPCell();
String imagePath; 
imagePath = D:\....;//specify any path

Image img = Image.getInstance(imagePath); 

img.scaleAbsoluteHeight(120f);
img.scaleAbsoluteWidth(120f);
img.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
leftCell.addElement(img);
leftCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

headerTable.addCell(leftCell);

PdfPCell rightCell = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph addText= new Paragraph("  This is required text", smallStandardFont);
rightCell .addElement(addText);

rightCell .setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
rightCell .setPaddingLeft(5);
headerTable.addCell(rightCell);

cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cell.addElement(headerTable);

return cell;


}
```