# droidText jar with how to set pdf in image with re size in android

Tags: android, pdf

I am using droidText jar for PDF create in my application but i can't re-size image and set text and image in same line. in my code i can get image in pdf but can not set with my size.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmimg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 2});

float documentWidth = 100;
float documentHeight = 100;
myImg.scaleToFit(documentWidth, documentHeight);

float leftMargin =  doc.getPageSize().getWidth() - myImg.getScaledWidth();
float lMargin = leftMargin / 2 ;
float topMargin =  doc.getPageSize().getHeight() - myImg.getScaledHeight(); 
float tMargin = topMargin / 2 ;
myImg.setAbsolutePosition(lMargin,tMargin);

table.addCell("\n\nRavi Vaghela");
table.addCell(myImg);

doc.add(table);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution about that. image and text set in same line and set to image fix size. show following my code:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmimg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("About Me::\n",catFont);
    p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
    doc.add(p1);


    Paragraph nk = new Paragraph("Nick Name",catFont);
    nk.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
    doc.add(nk);



    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(20); 
    p.add(new Chunk("RAVI", subFont)); 
    myImg.scalePercent(100); 
    p.add(new Chunk(myImg, 280.0f, -100.0f));
    doc.add(p); 


    Paragraph ppp = new Paragraph("SunSign",catFont);
    ppp.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
    doc.add(ppp);
```

with chunk we can add image and set size and position in pdf.
here subFont and catFont is FONT i have declared in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Robin

You can try **scaleAbsolute()** method  for resize Image like this,

```
 myImg.scaleAbsolute(documentWidth, documentHeight);
```

For Image and Text in Same line [How to display image and text beside each other Itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780258/how-to-display-image-and-text-beside-each-other-itext)